# typescript interface: optional but not undefined

Tags: typescript

How can I describe type like

> key is optional, but if it existed, it cannot be undefined.

At the first time, I'm using Partial to make all properties of T optional.

```js
interface A {
  a: number;
}

var data: A = {
  a: 1,
}

var update1: Partial<A> = {

}

var update2: Partial<A> = {
  a: undefined
}

var result1: A = {
  ...data,
  ...update1,
} // { a: 1 }

var result2: A = {
  ...data,
  ...update2,
} // { a: undefined }
```

The problem here is that result2 is not implementing interface A in runtime, but typescript never complains about it. Is it bug or feature?
I guess typescript not working well with spread operator...

The goal is distinguish these two variable using typescript!

```js
var data: T = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
}

var optional1: MyPartial<T> = { // Totally OK

}

var optional2: MyPartial<T> = { // OK
  a: 3,
}

var optional3: MyPartial<T> = { // OK
  b: 4,
}

var optional4: MyPartial<T> = { // OK
  a: 3,
  b: 4,
}

var undef1: MyPartial<T> = { // typescript must throw error
  a: undefined,
}

var undef2: MyPartial<T> = { // typescript must throw error
  a: 3,
  b: undefined
}

...
```

Check this out [TypeScript playground example.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20data%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20update1%3A%20Partial%3CA%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20update2%3A%20Partial%3CA%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20result1%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20...data%2C%0D%0A%20%20...update1%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20result2%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20...data%2C%0D%0A%20%20...update2%2C%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I don't believe it's possible, unfortunately, due to this (still) open issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195; there are some workarounds depending on how exactly you really want to use it, but a general solution seems impossible at the moment. :-/

Comment: this should really be supported.  I like using `Partial<T>` for redux action creators so I don't need to include all of the props on the `T` object (e.g., setting part of a User type while registering), but this allows me to potentially set the wrong property type :(

Answer (score 9):

Support now exists in 4.4.0 via `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`

> So by default, TypeScript doesn’t distinguish between a present property with the value undefined and a missing property ...
>
> In TypeScript 4.4, the new flag --exactOptionalPropertyTypes specifies
> that optional property types should be interpreted exactly as written,
> meaning that | undefined is not added to the type:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#exact-optional-property-types

Answer (score 4):

As @dtanabe mentioned, there isn't really a good solution here until TypeScript support (if they decide to). And main problem from doing it in user land is that in a var def (i.e. `const x: Foo = ...`) we do not have access to the type of the value. If you are OK changing your code from using spread to using a function you can do something like this:

```js
interface A {
  a: number;
}

type EnsurePartial<TTarget, TUpdate extends keyof TTarget> =
  undefined extends TTarget[TUpdate]
  ? never
  : { [Key in TUpdate]: TTarget[Key] };

declare function update<T>(propsToUpdate: EnsurePartial<A, T>): void

update({}) // OK
update({ a: 42 }) // OK
update({ a: undefined }) // error
update({ c: undefined }) // error
```

Comment: there is error in this code: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '"a"'.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in Dmitriy answer, here is the fixed version

```
interface A {
  a: number;
  b: boolean
}

type PartialWithoutUndefined<M,T> = M extends T
    ?  undefined extends M[keyof M]
            ? never
            : M
    : never


declare function update<M>(propsToUpdate: PartialWithoutUndefined<M,Partial<A>>): void

update({}) // OK
update({ a: 42 }) // OK
update({ a: undefined }) // error
update({ c: undefined }) // error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmRAFcBbAI2gG4dlzDyB7RgGwjhCwF8sswBPAA4oACnChhgcFgHVgYABaNiYAKogAJhBigIGgDwBZADQAVAHzIAvMkPIIAD0iaAzslNYAkAH5cxTdq6GvZOEK62ANoA1hD8jDC2ALpenj5EEABu0CmehIZehCCZ2bxaCCziKDD+CJKMIMjEghpwkEbmABSCUIyCLqaMqs2tEIRiElKy8koq6lo6RQYm45LS+qjm5gCUhBmMwBq8TS2QHRhcW8gA9FfIAPIA0ljHI2d4hAAsAEzIF9e3j2ew1OGHejQCCz0v0uN3sUB6UCBJwgbwQhH88yC0P+cIRvCAA)

weakness: it is impossible to type anything as undefined even if that is your intention

Comment: @DanielTate what do you mean?