# How do I make all optional fields required in TypeScript, but no more or less?

Tags: typescript

I have a type:

```
type SomeType = {
  hello?: string | undefined;
  world: number;
  meow?: string;
};
```

I want it to become the following:

```
type SomeTypeExplicit = {
  hello: string | undefined;
  world: number;
  meow: string;
};
```

By using this type, I want to enforce the “All optional properties should have the default value” rule in my components. Even if this default value if `undefined`.

However, if I use `Required<SomeType>`, I will get this, which is too strict:

```
type SomeTypeRequired = {
  hello: string;
  world: number;
  meow: string;
};
```

If I use [the elegant solution from “Required but possibly undefined type”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52973675/2008562) question, I will get the following, which is too loose:

```
type SomeTypeLooseRequired = {
  hello: string | undefined;
  world: number;
  meow: string | undefined;
};
```

How do I create such generic for `SomeType` → `SomeTypeExplicit` transformation?

Comment: If you're willing to turn on `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` then all you're looking for is `Required` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NVe0nw). If you're not, then this is impossible since `SomeType` will include `undefined` for `meow` even if you don't write it explicitly, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Woz4lm).  So, does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript interface: optional but not undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247101/typescript-interface-optional-but-not-undefined)

Comment: @jcalz, yes, I want to have `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` turned off. In this case, I don’t need to write extra conditions for HTML properties (e.g., I like when `aria-label` set to `undefined` simply doesn’t appear on the resulting markup).

Comment: @HenryWoody, it’s a question on another topic, but thank you for pointing out.

Comment: So then it's impossible. Do you want an answer saying "sorry, you can't do this, since `meow` already includes `undefined` in the types you've written."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) compiler option.

> With exactOptionalPropertyTypes enabled, TypeScript applies stricter rules around how it handles properties on type or interfaces which have a ? prefix.

For example, you can't assign `undefined` to a property marked as [optional (`?`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) unless `undefined` is assignbale to explicit type of the property.

```
type SomeType = {
  hello?: string | undefined;
  world: number;
  meow?: string;
};

declare const someType: SomeType;

someType.meow = undefined; // error
someType.hello = undefined; // allowed
```

`exactOptionalPropertyTypes` also affects how `Required` maps an objects properties marked as optional. When set to `true` unions that include `undefined` are preserved.

```
type RequiredSomeType = Required<SomeType>
// type RequiredSomeType = {
//     hello: string | undefined;
//     world: number;
//     meow: string;
// }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gWAFBRQAWEANqXAPwBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOZQA%20UArqwBMIAMzYQBAbnyEA7nEakBtVrwQAjCIykEoSODJr0mbdtoC%202-EIDGpAIaNo1uKwb1EKNLXhJUkS3h0Hn4QAHR6MlCY-EKirOISUAD0SVCajPL4Qb5ooSTkcFF8giJiksmpdgUy4vj4oJBQAEoQAI68zI4CPp6NmC3tneIAPD0hAHz4KVAN0AMdXWNoRbh404SE%20RS0DCwc3MWxZdrrG3IKSlAq6ponqRu6EPo7xhx3UGZAA)

Comment: Yes, it looks like a way to go, but there is one thing bothering me with `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` turned on. I need then to do extra handling of HTML attributes.

E.g., I want to set `aria-label` to something meaningful, but not to set it when there is nothing to set. For `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` turned off this is done automatically because of the SolidJS doesn’t add `aria-label` to resulting HTML when it’s `undefined`. When `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` is on, passing `undefined` is prohibited. If I try to replace it with `””`, then I get the undesired `aria-label=“”` in the HTML.